# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS while popping out a new View inside existing View

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I am trying to call a new view inside my existing view

```
TransactionFinish *childView= [[TransactionFinish alloc] initWithNibName:@"TransactionFinish" bundle:nil];

        childView.view.frame = self.view.frame;

        childView.view.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height-20);
        childView.view.alpha = 0.0f;
        [self.view addSubview:childView.view];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             childView.view.alpha = 1.0f;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         }];
```

It is going inside `ViewDidLoad()` of `TransactionFinish`(I have tried debugging it) but it gives me Thread `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x31f54e62)` with green color

Comment: did you try debugging with exception handling ?
You may get the exact line where your code crashes
.

Comment: @sergio I am not using ARC

Comment: You're loading a viewcontroller tho you just use the view later. It requires some work, but can you load just a view from nib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lays with the lifetime of `childView`. You instantiate and store a reference to it into a local variable:

```
TransactionFinish *childView= [[TransactionFinish alloc] initWithNibName:@"TransactionFinish" bundle:nil];
```

If you are using ARC, when the local variable goes out of scope, the object referenced by it (`childView`) is deallocated.

If you are not using ARC, I suppose you are doing:

```
[childView release];
```

somewhere to avoid `childView` to be leaked (as the code you pasted above would imply).

Either hypothesis would explain why you get the crash: when `viewDidLoad` is called, the controller has already been deallocated.

Adding `childView` view to `self.view`:

```
    [self.view addSubview:childView.view];
```

will retain `childView.view` but not `childView`. So the controller is deallocated, while its view is not.

A fix to this is creating a `strong` property in your class to store a reference to your `childView` controller:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) TransactionFinish *childView;
```

Another possibility is using [controller containment](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/); you could do something li

```
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:childView];
[self.view addSubview:childView.view]; // or something like this.
[childView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

but this will only work on iOS5+.

Comment: I have checked your previous answer, still the same. I am using iOS 4.1.

Comment: if you are not using ARC, are you doing a `release` on `childView` to avoid it to be leaked?